# Consulta SQL con valores Double

Tags: sql, vb.net

mi pregunta es como resolver este error
**La conversión de la cadena "update xcobrar set monto = " en el tipo 'Double' no es válida.**
He tratado cambiando los valores de double a string, y me da error al tratar de convertir la cadena lin de la consulta, em el evento button2 click, en la lien lin=update....

```
Public Class Cobros

Private Sub Cobros_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    comboapto()
    llenacombo()
    combobanco()
    DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12)
    'cargar numero de control
    Dim cmd7 As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    cmd7.CommandText = "select control from nrocontrol"
    Dim suma5 As String = Convert.ToString(cmd7.ExecuteScalar)
    Label4.Text = suma5
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dispose()
    MPpal.MenuStrip1.Enabled = True
    MPpal.Panel1.Visible = False
End Sub
Sub llenacombo()
    Dim Sql As String = "select tipo from formapago"
    Dim Dt As New DataTable
    Dim Da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, con)
    Da.Fill(Dt)
    ComboBox2.DataSource = Dt
    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "tipo"
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub
Sub combobanco()
    Dim Dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql2 As String = "select banco from bancos order by banco ASC"
    Dim Da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, con)
    Da.Fill(Dt)
    ComboBox3.DataSource = Dt
    ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "banco"
    ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub
Sub comboapto()
    Dim Dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql2 As String = "select apto from xcobrar order by apto ASC"
    Dim Da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, con)
    Da.Fill(Dt)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = Dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "apto"
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim apto As String = ComboBox1.Text
    If ComboBox1.Text = "System.Data.DataRowView" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView2.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        DataGridView2.Refresh()
        Label2.Text = ""
        Label12.Text = ""
        Label13.Text = ""
    End If
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "select nombres from propietarios where apto   = '" + apto + "'"
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read() Then
        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("nombres"))
    End If
    'llenar el mesex pendientes
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
    Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    cmd2.CommandText = "select mes, monto, dolares, nromov from xcobrar where apto = '" + apto + "'"
    Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
    Do While dr2.Read()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1(0, x).Value = Convert.ToString(dr2("Mes"))
        DataGridView1(1, x).Value = Convert.ToString(dr2("Monto"))
        DataGridView1.Columns("Column2").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
        DataGridView1(2, x).Value = Convert.ToString(dr2("Dolares"))
        DataGridView1.Columns("Column3").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
        DataGridView1(3, x).Value = Convert.ToString(dr2("nromov"))
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Mes"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Monto"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Dolar"
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    'llenar historial
    Dim sql3 As String = "SELECT fecha, mes, monto, formapago , fechaoperacion, referencia, banco FROM historial WHERE apto = '" + apto + "'"
    Dim dt3 As New DataTable
    Dim da3 As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim command3 As New OleDbCommand(sql3, con)
    DataGridView2.Refresh()
    da3.SelectCommand = command3
    da3.Fill(dt3)
    If dt3.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt3
    DataGridView2.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Fecha"
    DataGridView2.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Mes"
    DataGridView2.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Monto"
    DataGridView2.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Forma Pago"
    DataGridView2.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Fecha Oper"
    DataGridView2.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Referencia"
    DataGridView2.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Banco"
    '  sumar totales
    Dim nro As Double
    Dim cmd6 As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    cmd6.CommandText = "select sum (monto) from xcobrar where apto = '" + apto + "'"
    nro = Convert.ToDouble(cmd6.ExecuteScalar)
    Label12.Text = CDbl(nro).ToString("N2") + " BsS"
    Dim cmd7 As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    cmd7.CommandText = "select sum (dolares) from xcobrar where apto = '" + apto + "'"
    nro = Convert.ToDouble(cmd7.ExecuteScalar)
    Label13.Text = CDbl(nro).ToString("N2") + " $"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    If Not (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) _
```

AndAlso (Not e.KeyChar = "," Or TextBox2.Text.Contains(",")) Then
e.Handled = True
End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox4_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox4.KeyPress
If Not (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) _
AndAlso (Not e.KeyChar = "," Or TextBox4.Text.Contains(",")) Then
e.Handled = True
End If
End Sub

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'verificar(datos)
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Debe Seleccionar un apartamento")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ComboBox2.Text <> "Efectivo" And ComboBox2.Text <> "Divisa" Then
        If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar un monto")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe igresar una referencia")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ComboBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe Seleccionar un banco")
            Exit Sub

        End If
    End If
    'crear variables
    Dim fec As Date = Date.Now
    Dim apto As String = ComboBox1.Text
    Dim mes As String
    Dim forpag As String = ComboBox2.Text
    Dim fecope As String = DateTimePicker1.Value

    If ComboBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Debe especificar la cotización")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim lin As String
    Dim tas, deu, pag, monb, mond, dif, dol As Double
    tas = TextBox2.Text
    pag = TextBox4.Text
    'calcular el pago
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim nro As String
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Fila As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If Not Fila Is Nothing Then
                nro = DataGridView1(3, a).Value.ToString
                mes = DataGridView1(0, a).Value.ToString
                Dim sql10 As String = "SELECT monto, dolares from xcobrar WHERE nromov = " + nro
                Dim com10 As New OleDbCommand(sql10, con)
                Dim dr10 As OleDbDataReader = com10.ExecuteReader
                If dr10.Read() Then
                    deu = Convert.ToDouble(dr10("monto"))
                    dol = Convert.ToDouble(dr10("dolares"))
                End If
                If ComboBox2.Text = "Divisa" Then
                    mond = pag - dol
                    monb = tas * pag
                    dif = monb - deu
                    If mond < 0 Then
                        mond = mond * -1
                    End If
                    If monb < 0 Then
                        monb = monb * -1
                    End If
                    lin = "update xcobrar set monto = " + monb + ", dolares = " + mond + " where nromov = " + nro
                Else
                    mond = (pag / tas) - dol
                    monb = pag - deu
                    dif = monb - deu
                    If mond < 0 Then
                        mond = mond * -1
                    End If
                    If monb < 0 Then
                        monb = monb * -1
                    End If
                    lin = "update xcobrar set monto = " + monb + ", dolares = " + mond + " where nromov = " + nro
                End If
                If dif < 0 Then
                    'actualizar xcobrar
                    Dim sql7 As String = lin
                    Dim com7 As New OleDbCommand(sql7, con)
                    Dim dr7 As OleDbDataReader = com7.ExecuteReader
                    'actualizar historial


                End If




            End If
        Next
    End If

    'aumentar el numero de control
    nrocon()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución con esta cadena de texto.

```
lin = "update xcobrar set monto = " + CStr(monb).Replace(",", ".") + ", dolares = " + CStr(mond).Replace(",", ".") + " where nromov = " + nro
```